# what are the licensing requirements of vb6 programs

Tags: vb6, licensing

One of my friends is making commercial program in vb6 , is there any license required to sell the application to end user. He is having vb6 developer license.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the VB6 manual

You can freely distribute any application you create with Visual Basic to anyone who uses Microsoft Windows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa716256(VS.60).aspx

If you have used third-party controls or other components, you must check whether you can distribute them. This link lists some Microsoft controls that you can redistribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx

Answer (score 4):

There are no specific license requirements for VB6 applications that I know of. All that's important is that current operating systems ship with the VB6 runtimes, and for the moment that is true. The VB6 runtime comes pre-installed all the way up to Windows Server 2008 R2. There's a ton of useful information for your friend here:

**Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 and Windows 7**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx

-Oisin